# IOS-7 correct way to segue to a view that will never be recalled

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue

When a user launches my app for the very first time, they are presented with a "Home View" with two buttons. From there, they can modal segue to a "Login View" or a "Register View". This works fine because if the user changes their mind with login/register, they can hit back and I can return them to the "Home View" from the navigation stack.

When a user successfully logs in, I use a push segue to bring them to the first view internally in the app.

My understanding is now the two views (e.g Home View and Login View) are still in the navigation stack. This has no real value because the user would never normally return to these views.

Is there a better way to do this? Alternatively is this just a minor inefficiency and I shouldn't be concerned?

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to have two `UINavigationController`s in your storyboard. One for logging in/registering, and the other for the logged in state. Then, when the user successfully logs in, simply set the window's `rootViewController` to that of the logged in `UINavigationController`. Doing it this way will reduce your memory, as the logging in/registering `UINavigationController` is no longer within the stack.

This is what I do in my apps inside a method in the AppDelegate:

```
- (void)userLoggedIn
{
    self.loggedIn = YES;
    // Other properties here such as username, email, and password if necessary.

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                             bundle:nil];

    [self.window setRootViewController:[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoggedIn"]];
}
```

To call the method from the login/register view controller upon successful login/registering simply:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate userLoggedIn];
```